# drain of dataflow streaming job does not end

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I was execute "drain" for streaming job with this command

> gcloud alpha dataflow jobs --project=xxxxxx drain

but it does not end after three days!
this is log of this streaming job.

```
21:14:36.000
http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:40277: EOF
21:14:36.000
http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:36255: EOF
21:14:36.000
Kubelet is healthy?: true
21:14:42.000
http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:55731: EOF
21:14:42.000
Kubelet is healthy?: true
21:14:47.000
http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:60835: EOF
21:14:47.000
Kubelet is healthy?: true
21:14:48.208
Memory is used/total/max = 71/207/1801 MB, GC last/max = 0.00/0.00 %, #pushbacks=0, gc thrashing=false
21:14:48.403
Memory is used/total/max = 454/852/1801 MB, GC last/max = 0.00/27.00 %, #pushbacks=0, gc thrashing=false
21:14:49.020
Memory is used/total/max = 38/117/1801 MB, GC last/max = 0.00/0.00 %, #pushbacks=0, gc thrashing=false
21:14:49.245
Memory is used/total/max = 457/1092/1801 MB, GC last/max = 0.00/21.00 %, #pushbacks=0, gc thrashing=false
21:15:06.000
Kubelet is healthy?: true
21:15:06.000
http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:36348: EOF
21:15:06.000
Kubelet is healthy?: true
21:15:06.000
```

I was cancel this job. 
but I'm concerned about data loss.

I want to use "drain" instead of "cancel"
How can I drain streaming job ??

Comment: What is the job ID?

Comment: job ID is 2016-12-23_02_07_55-6029399430555331086 But I already canceled this job. And I started to drain another job 2017-01-03_17_29_25-3458753764339639310 now.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble - looks like you've hit a rare bug, we're investigating, but meanwhile you'll need to cancel the job. We do not know a workaround yet. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: thank you. i'm waiting for bug fix

Comment: We have a fix, however it will take a release cycle to roll out (typically 1-2 weeks).

Comment: Not sure if it is related. In our case, sometimes dataflow doesn't get out of a session window, even when the input stops completely. We are seeing a similar output and we have experienced a similar issue to the OP in the past (never finish draining). Our job id is: 2017-01-10_08_47_02-9496948080011212526 .

Comment: Seeing this same issue with a streaming job.

Comment: I will update this thread when the release is complete.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The release is complete and the issue should be fixed.

Comment: @jkff Thank you for the fix! Now my job draining works fine.

Comment: @jkff My Job Drain does not end again. It is draining 2 days. job name is 2017-04-11_18_30_14-1112716980101578556 StackDriver log prints this forever > Retrying 1 failed inserts to BigQuery

Comment: @gcpman Drain requires successfully processing all remaining data, so in general if your pipeline is looping retrying the processing of some records, your options are either 1) cancel the pipeline, or 2) update the pipeline with new code that will get rid of the failure, and then drain it. Unfortunately in this case you're currently stuck with only option 1 because code of BigQueryIO is outside your control and your pipeline already produced an unprocessable record - but this has been addressed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1151

Comment: So for now - cancel your pipeline and update to a new version of Beam (at HEAD), which will not have this issue. I am not sure if the new version of BigQueryIO is update-compatible: actually you may try to update your pipeline first, and if it works, then you'll be able to drain.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the comment thread: this was a defect in the managed Dataflow service, that has since been fixed by a release of the service.  The underlying issue was a priority inversion that caused a deadlock in message handling.